# how i can fill my data on just one bootstrap table django 2.1

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

---

[image]

my table looks like

- date        name     place 
  4.09.2018   jack     London

  date        name     place 
  4.09.2018   ed       paris

  date        name     place 
  5.09.2018   sam      istabul

i have problem with using table. i want to show one table my data but , it doesnt work, my program showing all my data different table but i dont want this. how i repair this situation ?

i want to show one header and all my data below from header like this

[image]
 - date        name     place

4.09.2018   jack     London 
   4.09.2018   ed       paris
   5.09.2018   sam      istabul

but this situation adding header for all of my data. it shows here

[image]

my html codes

thank u for your interest...

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
     <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'ANASAYFA'%}"> ANASAYFA </a>
        <br>
        {% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
{% for i in veriler %}
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">TARİH</th>
      <th scope="col">İSİM-SOYİSİM</th>
      <th scope="col">VARDİYA BÖLGE</th>
      <th scope="col">VARDİYA DÖNEM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="i.row">{{ i.gun }}</th>
      <th>{{ i.personel }}</th>
      <th>{{ i.bolge }}</th>
      <td>{{ i.vardiya_donemi }}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you expected as output

Comment: i edit the post. can u look again please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">TARİH</th>
      <th scope="col">İSİM-SOYİSİM</th>
      <th scope="col">VARDİYA BÖLGE</th>
      <th scope="col">VARDİYA DÖNEM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   {% for i in veriler %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="i.row">{{ i.gun }}</th>
      <th>{{ i.personel }}</th>
      <th>{{ i.bolge }}</th>
      <td>{{ i.vardiya_donemi }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
  </table>
```